# how to type or paste [ in osx terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am trying to use jq in my terminal but my terminal will not accept `[`. any time I try to type or paste it in my terminal just flashes and doesn't do anything. I've tried googling but can't seem to find a solution. It's not anything in my `.bash_profile` as I tried removing it all and still an issue

anyone have any Ideas how I might figure this out. I'm OS X 10.11 in case that's relevant

Comment: I don't know what "jq" is, but what if you try to type `[` in a regular Terminal window? (Works just fine for me.)

Comment: @arjan it is a regular terminal window, `jq` is just a command line tool to parse json

Comment: Do you have a ~/.bashrc or ~/.inputrc file?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I do not have either

Answer (score 1):

Is your <kbd>Control</kbd> key stuck? `^[` is the control-key chord to send the ASCII `ESC` character code.

Comment: not `Control` works fine other applications so doesn't appear to be stuck and `shift + [` works printing `{` in the terminal